# Identify duplicate Word in a string between rows

Tags: r, string, duplicates

I have a column with 5000 rows. My aim is to check every row with the next row if there are duplicated word. For example:

First Row : My name is Bobby

Second Row : My name is Boby

Third Row : This is your house

From the above example we can see that between the first and the second row there are 3 duplicate words, and between the second and the third row there is only 1 duplicate word. I want to make every row that have 3 or more duplicate word become one same Word. For example:

My name is Bobby

My name is Bobby

This is your house

I'm very new in r.. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you always want to use the first row in the data frame to be the one that replaces the later one?  What if you also had a row `My cat is Boby`?  What should happen in that case?

Comment: Looking at the example you gave, it seems to me that you want to do fuzzy replacement. If I am right, you may want to check stringdist package.

Comment: Despite having posted an answer, this is very unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the `tidyverse`. I created an example data frame called `dat` with five rows. Notice that the column is in character, not in factor. Please notice the outcome of this example. As you can see, row 3 and row 4 is very different, but because they have three common words, and because row 3 is similar to row 2 and row 1, eventually row 4 is replaced with row 1. Perhaps it is OK. I just want to show you that the condition you described could lead to this kind of situation.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  # Split the sentence
  mutate(V2 = str_split(V1, pattern = " ")) %>%     
  # Create a new column for the next word
  mutate(V3 = lead(V2)) %>%    
  # Count the number of intersection
  mutate(V4 = lag(map2_int(V2, V3, ~length(intersect(.x, .y))),
                  default = 0L)) %>%    
  # If >= 3 words are the same, set to be NA, otherwise the same as V1
  mutate(V5 = if_else(V4 >= 3, NA_character_, V1)) %>%   
  # Fill the NA based on the previous row
  fill(V5) %>%
  # Select column V1 and V5
  select(V1, V5)

dat2

#                            V1               V5
# 1            My name is Bobby My name is Bobby
# 2             My name is Boby My name is Bobby
# 3              My name is Boy My name is Bobby
# 4 This is your house name Boy My name is Bobby
# 5                R is awesome     R is awesome
```

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "'My name is Bobby'
                          'My name is Boby'
                          'My name is Boy'
                          'This is your house name Boy'
                          'R is awesome'",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

No 57-compiled package dependency "verse" required:

```
library(stringi) # helpful string function that stringr builds a crutch around

data.frame(
  V1 = c("My name is Bobby", "My name is Boby", "This is your house"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> dat

for (idx in 1:(length(dat$V1)-1)) {

  stri_split_boundaries( # split the strings
    stri_trans_tolower(dat$V1[idx:(idx+1)]), # turn elements lower case for easier comparison
    type = "word",  # split into words
    skip_word_none = TRUE # ignore whitespace
  ) -> words

  if (sum(words[[1]] %in% words[[2]]) >= 3) { # compare the word sets
    dat[idx+1, "V1"] <- dat[idx, "V1"]
  }

}
```